# Using Mockito in SpringBoot JUnit Test with @Async method will cause a null mock object

Tags: java

I test a async method in SpringTest JUnit. In ServerApplication.java, the default mode of @EnableAsync is PROXY. So in my async method, there exists some JPA operations, like repositoryCollection.clusterRepository.saveAll(). And in my test method, I need find data from database, like repositoryCollection.clusterRepository.listByClusterID(). Because it's async method, sometimes I can't find the data just put in by using saveAll. How can I test async method in JUnit test? The ASPECTJ mode will be not async.

```
@Async
public void asyncMethod (){
    //some code.
    repositoryCollection.clusterRepository.saveAll();
}

@Test
public void testAsyncMethod (){
    //some code.
    asyncMethod();
    repositoryCollection.clusterRepository.listByClusterID();
}
```